# Iterate and Get Input Value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am building React application and i have this problem. So i have a grid form with 'quantity' and 'price' input field in each row. How do i iterate and get the input value so i can sum it? Back in the day when im using jquery, i do it this way:

```
function CalculateTotal() {
        var tot_totl = 0;
        $('.detil_line').each(function () {
            var quo_quan = $(this).find(".m_quo_quan").val();
            var quo_hrgs = $(this).find(".m_quo_hrgs").val();
            tot_totl += (parseInt(quo_quan) * parseInt(quo_hrgs));
        });
        $('#m_tot_totl').val(tot_totl);
    }
```

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Bind the inputs to properties in your components, then average their values. You don't need jquery, nor should you loop through dom elements.

Answer (score 0):

If your content set in a object you can use 'Object.keys(your_object)' to get a key array of your_object. for example:

```
let your_object = {
  item1: {
    price: 10
  },
  item2: {
    price: 15
  }
}
let sumOfPrice = 0
Object.keys(your_object).forEach(item => {
  sumOfPrice += your_object[item].price
})
```